# Sorting a JSON file by outer object name

Tags: json, awk, sed, boost, jq

I have a json file `input.json` thus:

```
{
   "foo":{
       "prefix":"abc",
       "body":[1,2,3]
   },
   "bar":{
       "prefix":"def",
       "body":[4,5,6]    
   }
}
```

I would like to sort it by the outer object names, with `"bar"` coming before `"foo"` in alphabetical order like so:

```
{
   "bar":{
       "prefix":"def",
       "body":[4,5,6]    
   },
   "foo":{
       "prefix":"abc",
       "body":[1,2,3]
   }
}
```

to produce file `output.json`.

Versions of this question have been asked of Java/Javascript ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277715/how-to-sort-json-object-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values))

Is there a way to accomplish this using a command line tool like sed/awk or boost.json?

Comment: Objects in JS/JSON are unordered bags of key-value pairs, the property order has no inherent meaning. Why is the order important to you?

Comment: @knittl  (As always, things are quite complicated.) I have VSCode snippets as json files where the trigger keywords are names of outermost objects in this file. Visual Studio IDE snippets are not json files. They are stored in a different format with the trigger keywords themselves being file names allowing one to sort by their filename in Windows explorer. I am trying to match the two sets of snippets. I am not sure there is any other way to do this but sort the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq`, you could use the `keys` built-in to get the key names in sorted order and form the corresponding value object

```
jq 'keys[] as $k | { ($k) : .[$k] }' json
```

Note that `jq` does have a field `--sort-keys` option, which **cannot** be used here, as it internally sorts the inner level objects as well.

Comment: This does work for me. TY! The output prints `4`, `5`, `6`, etc., on separate lines. Is there a way to make the output exactly match the input file (in terms of total number of lines in the files) with only the specific lines of texts interchanged?

Comment: @Tryer jq does a default JSON formatting of the input, which unfortunately it doesn't allow to control for specific fields

Comment: re reformatting: see e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428312/custom-json-output-formatting-with-jq

Comment: To produce the desired output as given in the Q, you'd have to adapt this approach along the lines of: `[keys[] as $k | {($k): .[$k]} ] | add`

Comment: @peak yes indeed. I had to modify the suggested answer based on your correction to exactly get the output as I wanted in the OP. Your method also works perfectly. Hope Inian corrects his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variable-free jq solution:

```
to_entries | sort_by(.key) | from_entries
```

It is also worth noting that `gojq`, the Go implementation of jq, currently always sorts the keys within all JSON objects.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your answer -- should this be `jq to_entries...` instead of just `to_entries...` ? I had to install `jq` on my machine. It is not clear in your answer whether the utility itself is `jq` or some other utility.

Comment: @Tryer Yes, it's `jq 'to_entries | sort_by(.key) | from_entries' input.json`